# docker for mac failed to start

Tags: macos, docker

My docker for mac (1.12) setup has been working for a while now. All of a sudden, the daemon is not starting anymore - I think it happened after the Mac went to sleep and came out again - not sure.

Restarting the mac didn't solve the problem either. The whale icon at the top just keeps being animated. Below is what the diagnostic says.

I'll do a factory reset if needed but fear that I'll lost track of the storage that's been currently used by my images/containers.

```
Docker for Mac: version: 1.12.1 (2d5b4d9)
OS X: version 10.10.5 (build: 14F1909)
logs: /tmp/5C2E3EA4-9E4B-4647-809E-9370288CDAB2/20161101-180708.tar.gz
failure: docker ps failed: Failure("docker ps: timeout after 10.00s")
[ERROR]  docker-cli
         docker ps failed
[OK]     virtualization kern.hv_support
[OK]     menubar
[OK]     moby-syslog
[OK]     dns
[OK]     disk
[OK]     system
[OK]     app
[OK]     osxfs
[OK]     virtualization VT-X
[OK]     db
[OK]     slirp
[OK]     logs
[OK]     env
[OK]     vmnetd
[OK]     moby-console
[OK]     moby
[OK]     driver.amd64-linux
Failure: Could not upload diagnostic data to remote server (docker-diagnose exit code is 1)
```

Comment: Reinstall docker for mac. It'll pick up the local images you had.

Comment: Well uninstalling docker for mac actually removes everything. It does warn you before though.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same problem after upgrading my macbook to OSX Sierra.

I had to uninstall docker and install it again.

This solved my problem, even tho it wasn't the nicest way to solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a very similar problem: Upgraded to OSX Sierra, Docker was running fine afterwards, did some container and image cleanup, and then Docker would not connect (startup). Specifically the `docker ps` command was failing on the Docker CLI.

In Docker, I went to preferences -> uninstall/reset. I then had to copy over and create my images again, but everything is working well now.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Factory restart is always worth a shot. Sometimes it works for me.

Note: you will need to re-download your images.